# rubymine error - Could not find capybara-webkit-0.9.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capybara, capybara-webkit

When I try to run my application within rubyMine I get an error about capybara-webkit -

```
...
in `block in materialize': 
Could not find capybara-webkit-0.9.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

But I don't get it when running the app via the command line.

Seems like rubyMine is checking all environments even when I run development and it has an issue with this gem for some reason.

my Gemfile includes:
...

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "capybara"
  gem "capybara-webkit"
```

...

I am sharing a code base with another developer.
I use rubyMine, he doesn't.
We need capybara-webkit or similar for rspec tests.

**Note:

Rails 3.1.3

Ruby 1.9.2-p290**

I tried manually installing the gem from within rubyMine, gem manager, but still got error:

```
Following gems were not installed:
capybara-webkit (0.9.0):  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.          /Users/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb   Gem files will remain installed in /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capybara-webkit-0.9.0 for inspection. Results logged to /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capybara-webkit-0.9.0/./gem_make.out
```

Comment: I didn't.  Also it wasn't a rubyMine issue, got the same error at the command line.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use Capistrano to deploy to my production environment - bundler installs all the correct gems to a shared folder, but when it gets to assets:precompile it tries to load the :test and :development group gems, which don't exist in the bundle. I don't have a fix for this yet either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Mac OS X, then you need to make sure that you have installed all dependencies prior to installing Capybara WebKit.  Please see the https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.  Thus, you'll need to install  Qt 4 Mac and you can get installation instructions here:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/install-mac.html

Also, you can install it through MacPorts by doing 'sudo port install qt4-mac'.  Then you can install the capybara-webkit Ruby gem.